# Python: Fill dataframe column depending on other column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, numpy

My pandas dataframe:

| ID | String | Pet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is a cat |  |
| 2 | hello dog |  |
|  |  |  |

I would like to extract the pet from the `'String'` column and fill the `'Pet'` column accordingly.
The third row should be empty, and not filled by default.

My attempt:

```
df['Pet'] = np.where(df['String'].str.contains("cat"), "cat",
            np.where(df['String'].str.contains("dog"), "dog", '0'))
```

Unfortunately the empty (third) row also gets filled in my attempt.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: So need change `'0'` to `''` ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to, first, create a list with the strings that one see as pet, such as

```
pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
```

Then, using Python [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and regular expressions (using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) one is able to do the work

```
import re
    
df['Pet'] = df['String'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(pets)})', flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)

[Out]:

   ID         String  Pet
0   1  this is a cat  cat
1   2      hello dog  dog
```

---

**Note:**

- `flags=re.IGNORECASE` makes this approach case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for your default value:

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog']
regex = '|'.join(animals)

df['Pet'] = df['String'].str.extract(f'(?i)({regex})', expand=False).fillna(0)
```

output:

```
   ID           String  Pet
0    1  this is a cat   cat
1    2      hello dog   dog
```